# A $_POST should occur when submit form but is not?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, mysql

When I make a modification to data that is read into a form using MYSQL, I want to apply those changes to the database.  But even when successfully submitting a form, the `$_POST` values are not changing, they remain with the old values.
I am seeing the changed value in AJAX, and I even try an insert into the database with the values in AJAX, but that is not working...
I have spent days on this, can anyone help?  If I could get `if(isset($_POST['FirstName']))` to fire off, then I would be good, but I can't seem to get this to happen.  I will attach portions of my code, there is a lot, but I will attach the ones that are applicable.

```
// SNIPPETS FROM THE FORM:  This is contained in php_DOC.php
<form id="PhysicianForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" >      
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="CreateProfile">

// This prints out the modified FirstName value correctly, this is the only place I can get the modified value.  This is contained in php_DOC.php
    jQuery('#SubmitInsHrs').click( function () {
        var FirstName = jQuery('#FirstName').val();
            alert('FirstName being updated...', FirstName);
          console.log(FirstName);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'admin-ajax.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'action': 'post_language',
                'FirstNM': FirstName,

            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

These are in `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_jqery_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_CreateProfile','CreateProfile');

function CreateProfile(){
  wp_send_json_success( $_POST );
}


function enqueue_jqery_form (){
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-form');
}
```

I also tried this, to just force insert with new value, but no insert happens….

```
function post_language(){

    global $wpdb;
    alert('post_language is called');

    $FirstName = isset( $_POST['FirstName'] ) ? $_POST['FirstName'] : '';

    $table = 'Provider';

    $wpdb->insert( $table, array('FirstNM' => $FirstName));
}
add_action('wp_ajax_post_language', 'post_language');
```

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API endpoints for your AJAX requests instead? They're much easier to use and debug, if Admin AJAX fails it just gives you a cryptic message. REST API endpoints tell you in plain english why it failed. Also, your code doesn't sanitise or validate values, which can be a security problem, it just assumes the firstname is a first name, and not something else

Comment: Who can send this form? If the form is sent by a logged-in user, it's OK. But if it can be sent without logging into the WordPress, the proper action hook will be `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action-name}`, in this case `wp_ajax_nopriv_CreateProfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_post_language','post_language');
```

and then make either of following changes in your code.

Because your jquery code is sending `FirstNM` to server (not `FirstName`).
Therefore in `post_language()` function, change this line

```
$FirstName = isset( $_POST['FirstName'] ) ? $_POST['FirstName'] : '';
```

to

```
    $FirstName = isset( $_POST['FirstNM'] ) ? $_POST['FirstNM'] : '';
```

**OR**
Change `'FirstNM': FirstName,` to `'FirstName': FirstName,` in  ajax call.

```
data: {
            'action': 'post_language',
            'FirstName': FirstName,     // 'FirstNM': FirstName,
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
Also remove this line,from `post_language()` function if yo have not defined `alert()` in your PHP It seems to be a JS function added to PHP by mistake,  resulting in a PHP error.

```
    alert('post_language is called');
```

Comment: I think `FirstNm` => `FirstName` is indeed the issue here.

Comment: Well, I changed all occurrences of FirstName to FirstNM, so that all are the same.  FirstNM is the column name in my database.  FirstName is the form name.  But this did not fix the issue.  Thanks,

Comment: Did you added `add_action('wp_ajax_post_language','post_language');` to `functions.php`?

Comment: @phatskat you are right.

Comment: @Monica see the updated answer.